# Perforce Triggers - modify description text

Tags: perforce

I was looking through [Perforce : Prefill changelist description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015667/perforce-prefill-changelist-description) which is supposed to describe 1:1 how to create a `form-out change` trigger, which I did.

1. **p4 triggers file**

```
    suffix form-out change "powershell S:/p4_template.ps1 %formfile%"
```

2. **template file:**

```
(Get-Content $args[0]) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "<enter description here>", "template text"} | 
Set-Content $args[0]
```

However, I'm constantly getting the following error message:
'suffix' validation failed:

```
Execution Failed: powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 
    S:/p4template.ps1 /tmp/tmp.379055.140083088879040.130: No such file or directory
```

I did restart the perforce server as well (just because it was mentioned in that thread but looks like it doesn't really need to be restarted). From what I see, we want to have access to the tmp file and replace the text, but that tmp file `/tmp/tmp.379055.140083088879040.130` doesn't seem to exist? I've checked `%TEMP%` and set it as well with an ENV var. Further i'm getting this message in `p4v` when I click `refresh` and it does a `p4 change -o` operation.

Comment: Why is your script on a Windows path and your temp file on a Unix path?  What platform is your server running on and where is its temp directory?

Comment: @Samwise argh hold on the trigger is executed on the server?

Comment: Yup.  Otherwise any given trigger would only work for one specific client (or some set of very carefully configured clients).

Comment: I was expecting the latter, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for posterity: the issue here is that the trigger runs on the server, not the client, and presumably the `No such file` refers to either the `powershell` executable or the script not existing on the server.

Documentation on Perforce triggers: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/chapter.scripting.triggers.html